# TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable how to resolve this error while reading csv file

Tags: pandas, csv, machine-learning, deep-learning, confusion-matrix

> when I am writing this code

```
test_df1=pd.read_csv[CSVFILE]
```

> it show the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-13-cb3d7014d176>", line 1, in <module>
    test_df1=pd.read_csv[CSVFILE]

TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

> how to resolve this

Comment: I think this is typo `test_df1=pd.read_csv(CSVFILE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
test_df1=pd.read_csv[CSVFILE]
```

because `read_csv()` is a method so it is called by `()` not `[]`

so use :-

```
df1=pd.read_csv('CSVFILE.csv')
```